# How do I see a history of all SES emails sent with their contents? Mysterious emails were sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-spam

My organization's AWS account got an alert that we sent over 10,000 emails last week, many of which were marked as spam.

The catch is: No emails were supposed to be sent, we don't know who did it, and thus we're suspecting that it was a malicious actor.

**How can we see a history of all emails sent and log all future SES emails?** Specifically, can we see the contents of those emails? Is there a way we can determine who/which user sent those emails?

**I'd like to emphasize that I need to see all emails sent by SES**, regardless of region or any other parameters.

Any other tips or tricks?

This tutorial seems like overkill:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-sending-history/

Answer (score -1):

> How can we see a history of all emails sent and log all future SES emails?

yes using CloudWatch Metrics you can easily find all the metrics associated with ses, for future try using a notification system using cloudwatch and sns when something happens

Docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity-console.html

> Is there a way we can determine who/which user sent those emails?

Yes use cloud trail events

> can we see the contents of those emails?

I am afraid No, you can't, you might need to build custom solution like creating an event, and then processing contents with lambda.

Comment: How do I use CloudTrail events to log which user sent the emails?

Comment: You need to check CloudTrail `userIdentity` Element.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html
Usually cloud trail event are stored for 3 months by default so it is advised to log cloudtrail event in s3 bucket to query events older than 3 months and from there we use Athena to query logs on s3 bucket which give more power as it uses sql language. ( one of the best practice ).

If this answer helped you, possible to accept? so that it helps others in the future.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't answer so far. 3 months is more than enough of data storage.

Comment: You didn't get the point, you can always search the event in cloudtrail event `history`, I was talking about to implement a best practice for future if you ever want to search through event which are older then 3 months :)

Comment: But isn't CloudTrail overkill? I'd just like to log data for SES

Comment: please read my answer once again, I have mentioned the usage of cloud trail for who/which user sent the email, for log data for ses, use cloudwatch refer the link I have linked in my answer `In the navigation pane, choose Account dashboard. Your usage statistics are shown in the Daily email usage section.`
It will be more clear if you carefully read my answer :) Hope it helps